# Vista crashes on Updates

Tags: windows-vista, crash, windows-update

I restarted my system, but apparently it managed to download some updates. So, now when I am trying to load it it tries to install those updates, but fails and reboots my PC every time.
This failure looks like video driver fail (my monitor turns black for 20 seconds and then my computer reboots). I tried to run windows in safe mode, so it won't try to install new updates, but all I see is a black screen with a mouse pointer and then it gets restarted.

So, since I can't load the system, but I have full disk access, I am wondering if I can remove some cached files in windows folder in order to skip that updates installation process.

Answer (score 1):

Try the Startup Repair Tool that is available on the Windows Vista install DVD.

1. Boot to your Vista install DVD
2. Choose your Language
3. Click **Repair your computer**
4. Select the operating system you want to repair (you likely only have one) and then click **Next**.
5. On the System Recovery Options menu, click **Startup Repair**. Startup Repair might prompt you to make choices as it tries to fix the problem, and if necessary, it might restart your computer as it makes repairs.

More here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Startup-Repair-frequently-asked-questions